# GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported for Qt5 application

Tags: qt, gtk, qt5, qmake, gtk3

I have a very simple test case application with following config:

test.pro

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

...

PKGCONFIG = gtk+-3.0 appindicator3-0.1
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
```

it compiles well but crashes when executed with following error message:

```
Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

When I check the output binary with `ldd` or `lddtree` there is only gtk3 dependency but no gtk2. Why is this error then, any idea?

`test` is the binary file, here is the lddtree output:

```
$ lddtree test | grep gtk
        libdbusmenu-gtk3.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-gtk3.so.4
    libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0
```

Comment: Qt might be trying to load Gtk2 at runtime to fetch resources for the Gtk style.

I'm not sure what would be the best long-term solution, but for investigation you could try the command line argument "-style fusion".

Comment: You may be right about runtime gtk binding because giving `-style anything` skips the initial crash but on first interaction with the gui core dump error occurs.

So nobody uses Gtk3 with Qt then?

Comment: Trying to mix and match Qt with Gtk is just asking for trouble.  Why on earth would you do this?!

Comment: @MrEricSir I know I know but because of [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31762) there is no (easier) choice :(

Comment: If you are using gtk/appindicator only to set up an icon, you could perhaps do it in a separate executable that is not linked with qt.

Comment: @user4815162342 and then use `inter-process communication` every time user interacts with trayicon or application need to change the icon color for example. Himm sounds harder but I am not sure :/

Comment: Exactly. The inter-process communication can be trivial access through a pipe, which can be hooked to the event loops of both programs. I think it's a good fallback plan in case this fails to pan out. You could also look at how other Qt programs work around that bug...

Comment: @user4815162342 inter process communication for this simple task...oh my God...I'm sorry but gtk looks like hell to me, who designed this thing?

Comment: @JacobKrieg Inter-process communication is needed to avoid symbol clashes between gtk2 and gtk3, the former apparently being pulled by Qt into the executable. An actual Gtk application would not need inter-process communication for this task.